# Rails - method from the directory "/lib" doesn't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

In a controller action, I have this code:

```
  def import
    ImportJob.new("pah_to_file") # this doesn't work
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ImportJob.new("path_to_file") # this works
  end
```

When I run this action, the first line doesn't work, the second one does (the task is added to the Delayed_job queue and is processed).

I need to remove delayed_job and want to run the **ImportJob** as a "regular" method, but when I do that (as is shown on the first line), the method is not called.

The **ImportJob** method is located in the **/lib** directory. How to properly run it?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you `require` (load, basically) the file in your lib folder that defines the ImportJob class.  see http://brettu.com/rails-ruby-tips-203-load-lib-files-in-rails-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to call `.perform` on the *ImportJob* object instance in the first line:

```
ImportJob.new("pah_to_file").perform
```

This is how Delayed Job runs internally... basically a Delayed Job can be any object that responds to `.perform` and then, when running a job it starts by calling `.perform`.

Comment: I was curious - is there any way to run this object - ImportJob - from command line on the VPS as a unix script? The file name is **importjob.rb**.

Comment: Running it would most likely require a full rails environment. So you could make a rake task to run an arbitrary Delayed Job. Or perhaps a rails runner. Not sure about unix scripts in general.